# State domain, range, vertical asymptote and $x,y$ intercepts for $\log_4(x-1)+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

State domain, range, vertical asymptote and $x,y$ intercepts for $\log_4(x-1)+1$

I have the solution in the answers section of my book:

> Domain: $(1,\infty)$; Range: $(−\infty,\infty)$; Vertical asymptote: $x=1$;
>
> $x$-intercept: $(5/4,0)$; $y$-intercept: Does not exist

I am able to figure out everything except the $x$-intercept.

Domain:

$$x-1 > 0$$
$$x>1$$

Domain therefore is $(1,\infty)$ and the vertical asymptote is 1.
Range is $(-\infty, \infty)$ and there is no $y$ intercept because it's a log function.

For the parent function $\log_4(x)$ the x-intercept is $(1,0)$. How can I arrive at $(\frac{5}{4},0)$?

Granular, baby steps appreciated.

Comment: For the $x$-intercept, we want to find $x$ such that $\log_4(x-1)+1=0$.

Comment: For the vertical asymptote, you should write $x = 1$ since it is the equation of a vertical line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks all fine. You can solve the equation straightforward.

$\log_4(x-1)+1=0$

$\log_4(x-1)=-1$

Writing both sides into the exponent with base $4$.

$4^{\log_4(x-1)}=4^{-1}$

$x-1=\frac14$

$\vdots$

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm just learning about logs. Could you hold my hand on what exactly is happening on step 3, where you 'write both sides into the exponent with base 4'? It's a leap that I cannot follow

Comment: You put the terms into the exponents. Let´s say you have $a=b$. Then you can write both sides as an exponent of $c$: $c^a=c^b$.

Comment: Ok thanks. But why? Why do we do that, what's our goal? Sorry if this sounds obvious. I've never encountered this approach before (it's not in the textbook chapter I'm currently working through https://openstax.org/books/algebra-and-trigonometry/pages/6-4-graphs-of-logarithmic-functions#CNX_Precalc_Figure_04_04_201)

Comment: I can see or guess that's it's some form of cancellation. But what's the rule here? Sorry to push on, I'm just learning

Comment: You want to eleminate the $\log_4(\cdot )$, since you want to get nearer to $x$. How can this be done? Lets say you have the equation $\log_a(x)=b$, where a is the base and b is the exponent. This equation is equivalent to  $a^b=x$. That is our goal. To achieve that we write both sides into the exponent of $a$: $a^{\log_a(x)}=a^b$. And it should be clear that $a^{\log_a(x)}=x$.  Maybe you know better the identity $e^{\log(x)}=x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$-intercept (intersection of curve with $x$-axis) of $y(x)=\log_{4} (x-1)+1$ be $(a,0)$. This means to find $a$, one has to solve $$1+\log_{4} (a-1) =0$$

$$\Rightarrow (a-1) = 4^{-1}$$

> There is no $y$-intercept because it's a log function.

This is false. $y$-intercept is a point $(0,b)$ on the curve. For example, $y(x)=log_{4}(x+1)$ has $y$-intercept at $(0,0)$.

One has to check if $x=0$ is in the domain of $y(x)=log_{4}(x-1)+1$. Now argue that it is not. Domain is $x > 1$.